# How to order divs with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have divs like this:

```
<div class="oferta SYB">


 <div class="infoferta">
    <div class="datosoferta">
      <div class="ofertapagas">Pag&aacute;s<br/> $ 67</div>
      <div class="ofertavalor">Valor<br /> $ 160</div>
      <div class="ofertadescuento">Descuento $ 93</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

i want to order the divs with the class="oferta" by the value in "ofertapagas" or the value in "ofertavalor" or the value in "ofertadescuento", i dont know how to, i cannot use the database, i just can use Jquery, i am using the last version of it.
Some Help please!!

Comment: Can you only use Javascript/jQuery or can you change the output of the HTML as well? It will be easier if you can change the HTML like by adding the number you want to sort by to an attribute on the HTML element.

Comment: @Chris W. yes i can change the html

Comment: It looks like this should really be a table.

Comment: @Joaquin what do you mean by order, can you give an example of ordered divs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to order divs with JQUERY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317689/how-to-order-divs-with-jquery)

Comment: If you can change the HTML, you could add the raw values to the `div.offer` elements, e.g., `<div class="offer" data-pay="67" data-value="160" data-discount="93"> ... </div>` (alternatively, `discount` could be calculated). This will enable you to use jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method an do the sorting *directly on the `div.offer` elements*. (Combine this with @jAndy's solution to the duplicated question.)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery abstracts `Array.prototype.sort`. Since jQuery wrappet sets are *Array like objects*, you can just call `.sort()` on them or apply sort on them.

```
var $datosoferta = $('.datosoferta');

$datosoferta.children().detach().sort(function(a,b) {
    return +a.textContent.split(/\$/)[1].trim() - +b.textContent.split(/\$/)[1].trim();
}).appendTo($datosoferta);
```

See http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2011/02/did-you-know.html

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfsfs/

Comment: so.. first of all, in "classname" i have to put the classname that i want to compare right? but like i have text so i thing its not going to work.... i didnt explain, the div "oferta" repeats lots of times, and i have to sort that parent div useing the divs i explained earlier, i will have 3 buttons to send the class name each.... i need so to have in a variable the divs "oferta" sorted

Comment: @Joaquin: I updated the example. This is sorting for the *dollar value* (which is a little bit more trickery).

Comment: ok, but i dont understand whats in $datosoferta finnaly, i make an alert and it says [Object][object], i print html and its null

Comment: this is not what i want.... i need to order by parent, like this example:http://jsfiddle.net/Rfsfs/1/, do u understand?

Answer (score 0):

Using ui. [JQuery UI - Sortable Demos & Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

For your code;

```
$( ".offer" ).sortable({
   update: function(event, ui) { // do post server. }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place those offer DIVs in some sort of container (another DIV?) you can then fetch all the offers and sort by their childrens' values.

In the HTML below, I put the offer divs inside a container div, and added a `data-value` attribute to each of the child divs containing data, for easier access (no regular expressions required).

```
<div id="ofertas_container">
    <div class="infoferta">
        <div class="datosoferta">
            <div class="ofertapagas" data-value="67">Pag&aacute; $ 67</div>
            <div class="ofertavalor" data-value="130">Valor $ 130</div>
            <div class="ofertadescuento" data-value="93">Descuento $ 93</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infoferta">
        <div class="datosoferta">
            <div class="ofertapagas" data-value="57">Pag&aacute; $ 57</div>
            <div class="ofertavalor" data-value="150">Valor $ 150</div>
            <div class="ofertadescuento" data-value="43">Descuento $ 43</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infoferta">
        <div class="datosoferta">
            <div class="ofertapagas" data-value="107">Pag&aacute; $ 107</div>
            <div class="ofertavalor" data-value="250">Valor $ 250</div>
            <div class="ofertadescuento" data-value="1000">Descuento $ 1000</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="javascript: void 0;" id="sort_pagas" data-key="ofertapagas">Pag&aacute;</a>
<a href="javascript: void 0;" id="sort_valor" data-key="ofertavalor">Valor</a>
<a href="javascript: void 0;" id="sort_descuento" data-key="ofertadescuento">Descuento</a>
```

The JS / jQuery function:

```
ofertas_sort = function(sort_key) {
    // array of offer divs
    var ofertas = $('.infoferta');

    // the div classname corresponding to the key by which
    // we are sorting
    var sort_key_sel = 'div.' + sort_key;

    // in large lists it'd be more efficient to calculate
    // this data pre-sort, but for this instance it's fine
    ofertas.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt($(sort_key_sel, a).attr('data-value')) -
            parseInt($(sort_key_sel, b).attr('data-value'));
    });

    // re-fill the container with the newly-sorted divs
    $('#ofertas_container').empty().append(ofertas);
};
```

Here's the code on jsFiddle, with some links at the bottom of the HTML to demo the sorting: http://jsfiddle.net/hans/Rfsfs/2/

I changed some of the values to make the sorting more visible.